# WCF single method doesn't get called

Tags: wcf, azure-mobile-services, service-reference

this is crazy: I'm using a WCF-Client via ServiceReference.Service1 in VS2017 like this:
Webpage (CSHTML5) => SOAP-Request (WebClient) => Server is calling Azure Mobile Service => get Data back/written etc.

This works with 6/7 methods (some add items, some get items) but when I call the "delete" method the call doesn't reach the server and quit with an Error(500).

The Java Debugger talks about "SystemArgumentException: year"

So I ran the WCF Service on localhost to debug and every methods breakpoint works but no call at anytime I need that DeleteMethod.

Here my Operation Contracts:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Tour> GetTours(string _companyid);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddOrUpdateTour(Tour tour);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteTour(Tour tour);

    [OperationContract]
    bool CompanyLogin(Company company);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddCompany(Company company);

    [OperationContract]
    Company GetCompany(Company company);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateCompany(Company company);
}
```

And my Service1 class:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
{

    AzureDataService azureService;


    public Service1()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        azureService = new AzureDataService();
    }



    public List<Tour> GetTours(string _companyid)
    {
        var alletouren = azureService.GetAlleTouren(_companyid).Result;

        return alletouren.Where(e => e.Deleted == false).ToList();
    }

    public async void AddOrUpdateTour(Tour tour)
    {
        await azureService.AddTour(tour);
    }

    public async void DeleteTour(Tour tour)
    {
        await azureService.DeleteTour(tour);
    }

    public bool CompanyLogin(Company company)
    {
        return azureService.CheckCompanyAuth(company).Result;
    }

    public async void AddCompany(Company company)
    {
        await azureService.AddCompany(company);
    }

    public Company GetCompany(Company company)
    {
        return azureService.GetCompany(company).Result;
    }

    public async void UpdateCompany(Company company)
    {
        await azureService.UpdateCompany(company);
    }
}
```

This way I use the method in client-code:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client soapClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
                    foreach (var item in SelectedDoneTourDetail)
                    {
                        soapClient.DeleteTour(item);
                    }
```

This usage lead directly to an exception (500).

Please could anybody help?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I already deleted the [AzureVersion] property but no difference.

Here is my class Tour that I use with reference to the WCF-Service. I don't declare it client-side:

```
[DataContract]
public class Tour
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleted")]
    [DataMember]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TourID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FahrerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Reihenfolge { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Strasse")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Strasse { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Hausnummer { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PLZ { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Ort { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Notiz { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string GeoPoint { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AbfahrtZeitUser { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AbfahrtGeoPoint { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AbfahrtZeitClient { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AnkunftZeitClient { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Done { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double Distance { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsExported { get; set; }


}
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't figure out the real problem with serialization and skipped this problem by following workaround (may this helps other users) without knowing of best practise but now it works:

I changed my 'Delete' method to Delete(string itemid). Now the WCF-Service gets called and receives the id of my item. The Azure Mobile Service has a 'lookupasync' method to search for the id. Finally it deletes the requested object/record by id. I will add a null check and a workaround if there's no id but for now it works.

Comment: If an error 500 is returned but your breakpoint is never hit, that sounds like a serialization problem...

Comment: Thank you for the hint I tried a few changes within the model of my object-class with no effects. What's the best way to detect those serialization problems? I updated my question and show the underlying class. May there's a problem with the DateTime properties (the java exception in mind?)? Azure Mobile Service or the 'Easy Tables' don't offer a DateTime field, it's only a string field where the DateTime is stored. I wrote 3 Mobile Apps on that base, with RWD access without any issues yet. Since I have to use the WFC client, things getting harder :-)

Comment: Sounds like service and client proxy are out of sync. Have you re-generated the client?

Comment: Hi MarcE. What exactly do you mean with "re-generating the client"? I restarted the client several times while updating the code. Is there another workaround to get both in sync or is it measureable? Meanwhile another problem occured: the update method throws the same exception and never passes the wfc. I think it's the same origin...